# Integrating Google Place Picker API with Google Directions API

Tags: android-studio, google-places-api, google-directions-api

I managed to integrate Google Place Picker API in my code in Android Studio, but I still need to get driving directions from the current location of the device to the picked place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Place ID of the picked place.

The `destination` parameter of the Google Maps Directions API [can be a Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters):

> `destination` — The address, textual latitude/longitude value, **or place ID** to which you wish to calculate directions. ...

Note that in the `origin` and `destination` parameters:

> Place IDs must be prefixed with `place_id:`. The place ID may only be specified if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID.

See the [Google Maps Directions API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for full details and examples.